# Order by clause not working in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

My hql query is shown below but it is not ordering the records by a.remoteCreatedAt column, please help me if there is any mistake in order by clause.

```
SELECT c
FROM Comic c
JOIN FETCH c.album a
JOIN FETCH a.media m
JOIN FETCH c.user u
LEFT JOIN FETCH a.user ow
LEFT JOIN FETCH c.channel channel
LEFT JOIN FETCH c.categories cc
WHERE a.publishedAt !=NULL
  AND channel.uniqueName IN (:channelUniqueNames)
  AND channel.active = TRUE
  AND c.active=TRUE
  AND c.visibilityType='PUBLIC'
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN a.remoteCreatedAt !=NULL THEN a.remoteCreatedAt
             ELSE a.publishedAt
         END DESC
```

Comment: You should remove this question, because there was no problem with the query, as you note in your own answer below. If you leave the question up it will be confusing for other readers.

Comment: How can I delete the question? I think I wouldn't be able to do that because there is one answer which is up voted more than once

Answer (score 4):

One problem I noticed with your `ORDER BY CASE WHEN` statement is that you are trying to compare nulls with the `!=` operator.  Instead, you should be using `IS NOT NULL`:

```
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN a.remoteCreatedAt IS NOT NULL THEN a.remoteCreatedAt
             ELSE a.publishedAt
         END DESC
```

This is untested and there may be other problems with your query, but hopefully this rules out one possible reason for your error/unexpected results.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have tried this but this didn't help. != operator seems to be valid (internally hibernate converts to "is not null")since I have checked the sql query for this hql. If you want I can give you the sql equivalent of this hql generated by hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue in the query. Actually somehow this query was not getting executed. Sorry for trouble. Thanks Tim for your time. I learned lot of other things as well.